# WebUSB and FTDI232

Tags: webusb

I try to connect to a serial-usb interface (FT232) but can't find anything on how to configure it...

### What I've got :

- A serial to USB interface from FTDI, it's a [TTL-232RG-VSW5V-WE from this page](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm)
- A custom board sending messages through RS232

### What I need :

I need to connect to this interface using WebUSB, send messages, read messages.

### What I've achieved :

Right now, I can connect to the interface and "read" something.

## My problem :

I can't find anything on the web on how to configure the USB interface, the serial port configuration must be 57600 baud/s, E, 8, 1 but nothing I could find told how to configure these values...

See the following code, from what I understood, I've got to put some value in the `controlTransferOut` but I can't find what to put and why..

```
device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ 'filters': [] });
console.log(device);

await device.open();
if (device.configuration === null) {
    await device.selectConfiguration(1);
}
await device.claimInterface(0);
await device.selectAlternateInterface(0, 0);
await device.controlTransferOut({ /* WHAT DO I PUT HERE?? */ });
let result = await device.transferIn(1, 64);
console.log((new TextDecoder).decode(result.data));
```

What I can read from the "What I've achieved" section is single chars because the serial is not well configured.

I tweaked it though to kindda make it work, I've opened the serial port with another software, configured it, closed the other software, then connect to the USB interface with webusb and read messages. That worked, but way to complicated...

Any help would be REALLY appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [datasheet](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232RG_CABLES.pdf) your TTL-232RG-VSW5V-WE cable contains a FT232R chip. The datasheet for that is [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf). I was hoping to discover a description of the protocol that the chip supports but all I found was [documentation](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf) for their proprietary drivers.

On the other hand I know that Linux supports these chips so there must be code in the kernel driver for setting baud rate. The function in question is `change_speed()` in [ftdi_sio.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.c).

From this it appears that the control transfer you need to send is,

```
device.controlTransferOut({ requestType: 'vendor',
                            recipient: 'device',
                            request: 3 /* FTDI_SIO_SET_BAUDRATE_REQUEST */, 
                            value: divisor_value,
                            index: divisor_index });
```

`divisor_value` and `divisor_index` are the lower and upper 16 bits of the chip's clock divisor which is calculated by the `ftdi_232bm_baud_to_divisor` function based on the baud rate requested.

Hopefully this is a good start towards reading the code and figuring out what you need.

Comment: Indeed a good start! Thank you very much, I'll try to read this 2500 lines of code file and make it to work hopefully 

Comment: Hopefully you don't need to read the whole file. `change_speed()` and the function it calls to compute the divisor is really all you need. :P

Comment: Was anyone able to figure this out?

Comment: There's a table on the Arm website: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0183f/I49493.html

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, very much. It works like a charm.
I figured out for baud rate 9600:

```
    device.controlTransferOut({
        requestType: "vendor",
        recipient: "device",
        request: 3 /* FTDI_SIO_SET_BAUDRATE_REQUEST */,
        value: 16696, // divisor_value
        index: 48000000 // divisor_index
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, can't test it right now but can you add details about how to compute the `value` and `index` values?

Comment: I used `ftdi_2232h_baud_base_to_divisor` function from linux kernel source (eg.: [ftdi_sio.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.0/source/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.c#L975)).

The value is returned by this function, index is the base parameter (clock) from caller.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do this, I ended up creating an open source WebUSB FTDI driver guided by the Linux Kernel Driver which saves you from having to do the tricky stuff by hand and should work with any FTDI-compatible device providing at least the same functionality as the Linux driver (though, the official Windows' driver from FTDI has more ability to control certain features of certain chipsets).

https://github.com/Shaped/webusb-ftdi